# Eclipse: How to extract XSD using a XML?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

Is there a way to generate XSD inside of Eclipse using an existing XML instance text?

Answer (score 1):

in this closed Question: [How to generate an XSD from an XML file in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825028/xml-to-xsd-plugin) 
the first comment "http://code.google.com/p/xsd-gen" by srini.venigalla was a big help to me.
It's a **standalone jar** though.